# Custom branch for git

Tags: git, branch

I intend to checkout a custom branch in my project to include some specific features that must not be merged to master.  This branch will be maintained independently alongside the main branch.

If there are bugs fixed on my branch that I want merge to master without the custom features, what should I do, or how can I manage the branch like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cherry-picking allows one to merge individual commits. E.g.

`git checkout <your-feature-branch>
git log # record the hash of each commit you want to merge
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <hash0> <hash1>...`

Note that cherry-picking will not preserve the original hash of the commits. Also, the order of the hashes should be oldest to newest.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do an interactive rebase of your branch onto your local tracking branch so you can selectively pick the commits you want and dismiss the ones you don't want, use `git rebase -i`